# Why is my data forbidden when trying to display it on a web page?

Tags: http-status-code-403

I am in a group project with three other members where we are trying to connect to an API, store the data from that API into a shared database, and display it on a web page by accessing our code file through a server. For our project, we are connecting to four different music streaming API's, mine being Spotify. Individually, we wrote our own code in Python to connect to each of our API's and extract data to be stored in our own database. In my code, I searched the name of a particular musician, and when running the code, I connected to Spotify's API and received an output of that musician's top 20 tracks. Those 20 tracks were stored in a table in my own database in MySQL Workbench, with the columns 'tracks' and 'items'.

Now, each of my members and I have our data tables for our individual API's stored into one shared database in MySQLHosting.net. Currently, my group is struggling to print and display the data from each of our tables onto a web page. I have written a PHP file attempting to display my table for Spotify's data, and I saved the file on my server and ran chmod 755, but when I search for my PHP file in the browser, I am left with a

> 403 Error ("Forbidden: You don't have permission to access this
> resource").

Can anyone help me figure out if it is an error in my code, or if I need to run a different chmod command?  Below is the code I used to display my data.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <body>
        <?php

            $servername = "sql5.freemysqlhosting.net";
            $username = "[removed for question]";
            $password = "[removed for question]";
            $dbname = "[removed for question]";
            $port = "[removed for question]";

            // Create connection
            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname, $port);
            $mysqli = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname, $port);


            if (!$mysqli)
            {
                echo 'Connection failed<br>';
                echo 'Error number: ' . mysqli_connect_errno() . '<br>';
                echo 'Error message: ' . mysqli_connect_error() . '<br>';
                die();
            }
            echo 'Successfully connected!<br>';


            $sql = "SELECT tracks, items FROM spotify";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0)
            {
                // output data of each row
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                {
                    echo "tracks: " . $row["tracks"]. "<br>" . "items: " . $row["items"]. "<br>";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo "0 results";
            }

            $conn->close();

        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would FIRST ensure the file you are looking for is available to the web server.  After that -- 1) print the supposed file directory from your script .. Make sure it's actually "there" 2) physically go to that file through your back end and make sure it exists.  3) do a `ls -lah` to ensure the permissions are what you think they are.

Comment: `mysqli_connect()` is an alias of `new mysqli()`. https://www.php.net/function.mysqli-connect You shouldn't need both. The `mysql_connect()` function using all the same arguments should be a hint that you are doing something extra.

Comment: This is a http error code and is unlikely to come from php and definitely has nothing to do with html or mysql. Webserver / operating system level configuration is the likely root cause of the error.